# causal sketches

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, causality

I don't have much of an idea of how to draw causal sketches. I know that you need to work out the gradient of the light cones, which can be done using a given metric and using null vectors. But how do you use null vectors to work out the gradient of metric?

I've got a metric of $ds^2=-dt^2+(e^t)(dx^2)$ that I need to draw a causal sketch for. How do I find the gradient (using the null-vector), to draw light cones for a causal sketch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null curves have:

$$ 0 = ds^2 = -dt^2 + e^t dx^2$$

that gives you the null curves differential equation:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = e^{-t/2} $$

Solving it you get the equation of the null curves, and so the light cone.

Comment: how do I solve the differential equation? :/

Comment: $\int dx = \int e^{-t/2} dt$  Don't forget the constant of integration